# decrease results of openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

```
class Cryptography {
    public function encrypt($string) {
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher='AES-128-CBC');
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
        $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($string, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
        return base64_encode($iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw);
    }
    public function decrypt($encryptedString) {
        $c = $encryptedString;
        $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
        $iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
        $hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
        $ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
        $decryptedString = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
        if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
            return $decryptedString;
        }
    }
}
```

this is just one of the results of encryption.

```
3cV/FVGk/gpIofUs5GL3DTid8FOZTXPivxat7+SZG+ARqPWiRUMazeq2cOJpCjzmVzN8arFcl7VDSC6nFvh1CA==
```

how can I decrease it something like half of it but the encryption and decryption still works.

Comment: If you want to decrease it in size, it won't be the same encryption. Why does it matter? If it's a good encryption, just let it be. It's when people are trying to be clever they accidentally weakens the security.

Comment: It isn't clear from your question what it is that you want to decrease.

Comment: the result of encryption

Comment: There certainly are ways of decreasing the *size of the ciphertext* but as we don't know the requirements for the encryption or the ciphertext (e.g. text or binary) this will be impossible to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways of decreasing the size of the ciphertext:

1. decrease the amount of plaintext (e.g. a more dense format or compression);
2. decrease the size of the IV or calculate the IV from a known unique number instead of including it with the ciphertext;
3. use a mode of operation that doesn't require padding (OpenSSL / CBC uses PKCS#7 padding by default);
4. make the size of the authentication tag (HMAC value) smaller by taking the leftmost bytes;
5. remove the base 64 encoding or use a more dense encoding.

Neither option - except possibly the first - will decrease the ciphertext to 50% of the original for larger messages. Only creating a smaller plaintext - for which the result is of course unknown - or removing the base 64 has direct influence on the number of bytes taken up by the actual ciphertext. The ciphertext grows linearly with the plaintext for CBC and most other modes of encryption.

Removing base 64 will decrease the ciphertext size with 25% and possibly a few bytes of padding / overhead. But you will have to deal with binary ciphertext consisting of bytes with a (pseudo-) random value.

---

Table with estimated savings:

1. plaintext reduction / compression: unknown;
2. iv reduction: max 16 bytes for no included IV;
3. no padding: max 16 bytes if no padding is required;
4. HMAC reduction: 24 bytes for an 8 byte tag (living dangerously here);
5. no encoding: 25% and a few bytes, possibly

---

Notes:

- compression may lead to side channel attacks - it wasn't removed from TLS without reason;
- the IV must remain unique and - for CBC mode - random;
- decreasing the size of the authentication tag below a certain threshold may of course decrease the level of security offered - how much depends on how/when the messages are verified.